# Ruby use CSV headers to create lookup table

Tags: ruby, csv, header

I have a simple but large CSV that contains the name of an item in the first column and then a handful of related attributes on the row. How do I find a specific attribute of the named item using the CSV class?  Thank you in advance for your help!

CSV:

```
Item, expected, percent_tol, low_limit, high_limit,
   a,        1,          10,       0.9,        1.1
...
```

What I have now:

```
limits_table = CSV.parse(File.read('limits.csv'), headers: true)

limits_table.each do |item|
  a_expected = item['expected'] if item['name'] == 'a'
  ...
end
```

Comment: It looks like the key for the first column is Item. So Instead of `item['name']`, use `item['Item']`.

Answer (score 0):

**Remark:** In your example you don't seem to be aware that the white spaces are considered part of the data in CSV files; you'll need to deal with them while reading the file. If you have control over the CSV creation upstream then I recommend to generate the file like this:

```
Item,expected,percent_tol,low_limit,high_limit
a,1,10,0.9,1.1
...
```

I'll assume that you don't have any control over the CSV creation, so I will strip the white spaces while reading the file.

You can use `CSV#find` to extract the first item that matches your condition

```
limits_table = CSV.parse(File.read('limits.csv'), headers: true)
item_a = limits_table.find { |row| row['Item'].strip == 'a' } # 'strip' is needed when you have irrelevant white spaces in your CSV file
a_expected = item_a[' expected'].strip # using ' expected' instead of 'expected'
```

Also, reading a whole CSV file into memory may cause problems when dealing  with huge files; in that case you should use `CSV#foreach`

```
a_expected = nil
CSV.foreach('limits.csv',headers: true) do |row|
  if row['Item'].strip == 'a'
    a_expected = row[' expected'].strip
    break
  end
end
```

Note that you should avoid calling `CVS#foreach` twice, because reading a file from disk is slow. So you'll need to do all your data extraction in one pass, if possible.

```
# extracting 'expected' field of items 'a', 'x' and 'y':
expected = { 'a' => nil, 'x' => nil, 'y' => nil }
count = expected.keys.count
CSV.foreach('limits.csv',headers: true) do |row|
  id = row['Item'].strip
  if expected.has_key?(id)
    expected[id] = row[' expected'].strip
    count -= 1
  end
  break if count == 0
end
# now you can use "expected['a']" instead of "a_expected"
```

If your file is not that big and you want to access the data by "Item", and the "Item" field contains a unique identifier, you can load your data in a more convenient way, while removing the unwanted white spaces in the process:

```
items = {}
CSV.foreach('limits.csv',headers: true) do |row|
  id = row['Item'].strip
  raise "duplicate item '#{id}'" if items.has_key? id
  items[id] = {}
  row.each_pair { |k,v|
    next unless k && v # This shouldn't be necessary when each row has the same number of fields than the header
    items[id][k.strip] = v.strip
  }
end
items['a']['expected'] # => "1"
```

**BTW** your CSV has a comma at the end of the header line, which generates an empty column for all the following rows. You should remove it.

Comment: This is an excellent and very detailed answer.  Thank you for your help!